# What is the song in Demon School episode 8?

Tags: music, welcome-to-demon-school-iruma-kun

In *Welcome to Demon School! Iruma-kun* episode 8, there is a song that starts at 15:10 and finishes at 17:05.

What is the name of the song, and who produced it?

Comment: Is that the "Who's the cutest in the world? It's Clara!" song? Given that the OP and ED have only just been released recently, you'll probably need to wait for the official soundtrack album (if there is one).

Comment: @ConMan Yes, that sound like it could be the correct title. But searching for it comes back with nothing.

Comment: You probably won't find much useful. It's not named in the opening or ending credits, which is standard practice for insert songs that might get some kind of proper release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i couldnt find anything in english but this is the japanese name a spotify link and a youtube one
クララランド～奇跡のちゅちゅちゅ～
https://open.spotify.com/artist/4d642R2q2J5re3gpzEi5uw
https://youtu.be/NkK9BR0rk0U